# Returning MongoDB Items in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to understand how Meteor returns database records. I'm running the following code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  items(){
    return Items.find({});
  },
  json(){
    console.log(this.items());
  },
  loggedIn(){
    return Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

I'm a little confused as to why this json method doesn't just output and array, or more specifically why the child values don't really seem to just return an array of values.

I can get the values inline html using spacebars, but I'm not sure how to access those values through js. What simple thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`Collection.find()` in Meteor returns a *cursor*, which is a function that can be used by Blaze templates (for example).

`Collection.find().fetch()` returns an array of objects (i.e. *documents*).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Subsequently, because the fetch function is related to the find function, does that mean I have to do two individual finds if I wanted to use both the Blaze cursor AND output a stringified json array/object?

And are Session's the best way to create globally accessible variables?

Comment: You don't need to do two finds. You can just do `const cursor=Collection.find()` and then later `console.log(cursor.fetch())`. Sessions are great as global *reactive* variables (i.e. when they change any dependent code will also run). You should also look at [reactive vars](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the database record between multiple helpers or even between templates and routes, why don't you use session variables.

For your example:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  items(){
    const items = Items.find({});
    Session.set('itemArray', items);
    return items;
  },
  json(){
    console.log(Session.get('itemArray');
  },
  loggedIn(){
    return Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: This certainly clears up how not to make multiple queries, but I'm still not sure how to access the documents (records) that are being returned. 

Maybe a better way to frame this question is, what's the best way to do a find and just output the resultant documents (object) to the console?